# window.plugin.notification.local.getScheduledIds return only one object although notifications are added before

Tags: cordova

i need to add dynamic add to the notification and for that i am using this technique

```
   var abc=1;
         window.plugin.notification.local.getScheduledIds(function(scheduledIds) {
          scheduledIds.sort()
            for (var i = 1; scheduledIds.length > i; i++) {
              abc=i;
                }
          });
```

and in the each loop where  i am generating the notifications:

```
for (i=0;i<selectedDays.length;i++){
abc++;
              var notificationObject = {
                  id:abc,
                  title:'Prayer Time',
                  message:'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
                  repeat:'weekly',
                  date:null,
                 json: JSON.stringify({
                    category: cat,start_time:startTime,end_time:endTime }
                                      )
              };


              var  notificationObjectMonday = jQuery.extend(notificationObject, {
                  date : newactualdate
               });
                window.plugin.notification.local.add(notificationObjectMonday);

             }
```

and now problem is that on the first time its give me this

```
["1"]
```

which is fine and after all plugins added its give me this:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
```

and when i goto another page and come back its give me this again:

```
 ["1"]
```

it should give me this:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
```

i can add more from 9,10,11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try any random number and use loop index